# Efficient Method for Breaking RSA?

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to find a more efficient way how to break the RSA cipher.
Bellow very non-optimal applet break simple RSA cipher using public exponent and modulus. Remember that it is brute-force attack, so breaking time depend on your machine.

EDIT: I'm looking for a code-based solution, not for theory about how to solve a problem.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class RSACracker extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;
    String[] fieldNames = {
        "Modulus(n):",
        "Public exponent(e):",
        "Cipher(c):",
        "Message(m):"
    };
    JComponent[] jca = new JComponent[fieldNames.length];
    int[][] fs = {
        {
            16,
            1
        },
        {
            16,
            1
        },
        {
            16,
            1
        },
        {
            16,
            10
        }
    };
    Container cp;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 5);
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; ++i) {
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
            cp.add(new JLabel(fieldNames[i]), gbc);
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            if (fs[i][1] == 1) {
                JTextField tf = new JTextField(fs[i][0]);
                jca[i] = tf;
                cp.add(tf, gbc);
            } else {
                JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(fs[i][1], fs[i][0]);
                ta.setLineWrap(true);
                ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(ta,
                    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                jca[i] = ta;
                cp.add(jsp, gbc);
            }
        }
        JButton b = new JButton("Calculate");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        cp.add(b, gbc);
        cp.setSize(400, 400);

        //My Test: p=51407, q=63667, message=123456
        ((JTextComponent) jca[0]).setText("1760806643"); //n - modulus
        ((JTextComponent) jca[1]).setText("65537"); //e - public exponent
        ((JTextComponent) jca[2]).setText("818474911"); //c - cipher

        //Wiki Test: p = 61 and q = 53, message = 65
        //  ((JTextComponent) jca[0]).setText("3233"); //n - modulus
        //  ((JTextComponent) jca[1]).setText("17"); //e - public exponent
        //  ((JTextComponent) jca[2]).setText("2790"); //c - cipher
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        setSize(450, 450);
        repaint();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        BigInteger n = new BigInteger(((JTextComponent) jca[0]).getText());
        BigInteger e = new BigInteger(((JTextComponent) jca[1]).getText());
        BigInteger c = new BigInteger(((JTextComponent) jca[2]).getText());

        BigInteger p = BigInteger.ONE;
        BigInteger q = BigInteger.ZERO;

        while (true) {
            p = p.add(BigInteger.ONE);
            if (n.mod(p).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
                q = n.divide(p);
                if (p.multiply(q).compareTo(n) == 0)
                    break;
            }
        }
        BigInteger totient = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
        //  System.out.println("p="+p+"\n"+"q="+q+"\n"+"totient="+totient);

        BigInteger d = e.modInverse(totient);
        BigInteger m = c.modPow(d, n);

        ((JTextComponent) jca[fieldNames.length - 1]).setText(m.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Breaking RSA first requires properly formatted code.

Comment: To the right when you were asking your question there was this handy **How to Format** box. Worth a read, as is [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area.

Comment: Vote to close: Not a real question (just "give me some code").

Comment: My bad, I have script-blocking add-ons in my browser so edit window show without tools panel and it was impossible to format text in right way.

Comment: You can look at http://axion.physics.ubc.ca/pgp-attack.html to learn more about attacks on RSA.

Comment: @Yetii: Um, sure, pull the other one. Your add-ons prevented you from typing four spaces? From seeing the preview was rubbish? From seeing the published question had issues and clicking the **edit** link?

Comment: To answer your question as per the title, massive improvements in our ability to factor integers into their prime factorisations. Just trying every number between 1 and... whatever works is definitely not how you break RSA. Knowing these parts of the key is not connected to the use of compression in the cipher and intercepting a public key is not a man-in-the-middle attack. Public keys are *exactly* that - public.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: NoScript block quantserve.com and without they script edit box look like simple text area - as mention before, no edit tool box and preview was shown. May it will be good idea to change script location to main server.

Comment: @Yetii: Again: When you posted your question, you saw the result. At that point, it's incumbent upon **you** to fix it. Not a biggie, but let's not blame tools you choose to use, eh?

Comment: @Ninefingers: attack is just example how to catch information from "handshaking"(public key sharing) transmission. Generally you don't receive information about public exponent and modulus if you are not participate on transmission.